# Unable to create Bing services through Terraform/AZ CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, pipeline, azure-cli

Bing.search.v7 is not getting created through either Terraform or AZ CLI

I want to create bing.search.v7 in the portal either through Terraform or AZ CLI. The Terraform earlier had support for it under Cognitive Services, but now it has moved out of it and currently not supported by Terraform. I tried using AZ CLI also but to no avail. Is there any way I can create the above mentioned resources by these two ways? If not what is the possible solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to deploy the BingSearch.v7 through Terraform using the following:

```
    resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "main" {
  name                = var.cognitive_service_name
  resource_group_name = var.cognitive_service_resource_group_name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
  parameters_content = jsonencode({
    "name" = {
      value = var.cognitive_service_name
    },
    "location" = {
      value = "Global"
    },
    "sku" = {
      value = var.sku_name
    },
    "kind" = {
      value = var.kind
    }
  })
  template_content = <<TEMPLATE
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "kind": {
          "type": "String"
        }

    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-10",
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Bing/accounts",
            "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
      "accessKeys": {
          "type": "object",
          "value": {
              "key1": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Bing/accounts', parameters('name')), '2020-06-10').key1]",
              "key2": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Bing/accounts', parameters('name')), '2020-06-10').key2]"
          }
      }
   }    
}
TEMPLATE

}
```

and how to retrieve those keys:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.main.id

  name         = "bing-service-access-key"
  value        = jsondecode(azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment.main.output_content).accessKeys.value.key1
}
```

Comment: This ARM template is working for me. Thanks for that. How can I store primary and secondary access keys in the key vault after resource creation?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, you must add another block at the same level as the "resources". I edited the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried deploying the Bing Search V7 by keeping the kind value and by using the this sample terraform template [shared here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cognitive_account) and it got failed.

As mentioned in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-web-api-v7-reference),Starting from October 2022 Bing Search APIs are moving from Cognitive Services to Bing Search Services.

You can deploy the Bing Web Seach API V7 using either through portal or through ARM template successfully Here is the sample ARM template I have used

```html
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type":"Microsoft.Bing/accounts",
            "apiversion":"2020-06-10",
            "location":"Global",
            "name":"<BingSearchName>",
            "sku":{
                "name":"S1"
            },
            "Kind":"Bing.Search.v7",
            "properties":{
                "statisticsEnabled":false
            }

        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```